# Why the transition from log in page to main page doesn't work (swift)?

Tags: swift, firebase-authentication, transition

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afn05.png)
I'm new in programming (swift). I tried to create a login page with Firebase authentication (it worked) but at the transition from the login enter code here` page to my main page (map) I get this error

- Closure expression is unused
- Expected expression after operator
- Reference to property 'EmailField' in closure requires explicit use of 'self' to make capture semantics explicit
  thank you for the help

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

```
    view.addSubview(EmailField)
    view.addSubview(PasswordField)
    view.addSubview(LoginButton)
    
    
    LoginButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapButton), for:.touchUpInside)
    
    
    if FirebaseAuth.Auth.auth().CurrentUser ! = nil  {
        EmailField.isHidden = true
        PasswordField.isHidden = true
        LoginButton.isHidden = true
        
    
        view.addSubview(Mapviewcontroller)
    
    }

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afn05.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
let vc = Mapviewcontroller()
self?.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

You can't write "! =", it has to be together "!=".

Like your error says, u have to use self in closures.

```
self.EmailField.isHidden = true
```

Remove view.addSubview(Mapviewcontroller), you can't add view controllers to view. You can push them to stack, present them, etc.